# I need a function that ask the user to enter a pin and after 3 wrong attempts, they program terminates

Tags: c, function, terminate

I have to write an ATM program for a class, and i cant figure out how to make a function that will ask the user for a pin and if the pin is entered incorrectly three times the program will display an exit message then terminate.... this is what i have some far. I think my issue is i don't know the correct syntax to handle my issue.

I know i will need a for loop but not sure how exactly to construct it.

```
void validate_acc(){
     int user_acc_try;

     printf("Please enter your account number: ");
     scanf("%d", &user_acc_try);

     if(user_acc_try != account_number){
                     printf("You entered the wrong account number");
                     }
     else{
          printf("");
          }
}

void validate_pin(){
     int user_pin_try;

     printf("Please enter your pin number: ");
     scanf("%d", &user_pin_try);

     if(user_pin_try != pin){
                     printf("You entered the wrong pin number.");
                     }
     else{
          printf("");
          }
}

void validate(){
     validate_acc();
     validate_pin();
}
```

Secondly, since i can only post every 90 minutes might as well ask another question, I do not know how to make a function go back to the beginning of my program like for example say after an deposit, what is the logic i would need to use to have a function go back to the beginning of my main function. I know of `goto` `labels`, that didnt seem to work when i put it in front of my main function like so...

```
MAIN:
int main()
```

i would put `goto main;` in another function and i would get a.... Main is not defined error. I have read a few different questions on here about labels but cant find anything that helps, if someone could guide me in the right direction, you would be giving me a great deal of relief.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to write out a flow chart for things like this if you can't figure out how to do it in code.

Please do not use labels/goto in C.  It's a nasty habit and it's not needed.

You know how to use if statements to make a decision; think about how you would use a `while` loop to try to make the same decision over and over again until something changes.  For instance, in pseudo-code (because I don't want to do your work for you)

> user_has_not_entered_correct_pin = true 
>  retries_left = 3 
>  while retries_left > 0 and user_has_not_entered_correct_pin: 
>    get pin 
>    if pin_is_not_correct(pin) retries = retries - 1
>    else user_has_not_entered_correct_pin = false
>  end while

Comment: Eric your awesome, and i thank for the pseudo code giving me a chance to think it out myself.

Comment: A nice answer that actually gives the OP what they need rather than just providing the code

Answer (score 0):

I am limited on time right now, so I will just post a quick help. I would suggest start researching loops in C. Since this is for a class, the book you are using should have information in it about for loops and while loops, but if not, a simple Google search can help a lot.

With a quick search on Google, this site seemed like a decent site for basic information on loops:
[Loops in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm)

It has links and examples of using a for loop, a while loop, a do...while loop and nested loops which should help you solve your problem.

Edited to add:
In your post you mentioned that you think the problem is that you don't know the syntax that you need. It is for that reason that I pointed you to a location that can help you with the syntax that you need to solve your problem rather than show you directly how to solve the problem. I hope that this helps you not only with this question, but going forward in your class as well.

Comment: I edited my answer to say why I pointed you to a link rather than how to directly solve this problem. It has been a decade or so now since my first programming class. In my experience since then I have found that learning how to learn the syntax of programming languages is an extremely useful tool when programming. Good luck with the class! :)

Comment: After seeing Eric's answer, I wish I had enough rep to mark his answer as useful. His was significantly better than mine. :)

Comment: haha, i mean you took your time out to find links and you typed alot, both helped me in the long run(:

Comment: That is great! I am still relatively new to answering questions on StackOverflow. I am definitely going to learn from Eric's example as a good way to answer similar questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Keep a count variable like I have did below and check the number of attempts:
I don't see a need for `goto` here. The same logic can be used for checking pin also.

```
int i=0;
while(1)
{
  if(i>2)
  {
    printf("Maximum attempts reached\n");
    break;
  }
  printf("Enter the acc_num\n");
  scanf("%d", &user_acc_try);
  if(acc_num == saved_acc_num)
  {
    // Do your stuff
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Return value from  validate_pin() `int  validate_pin(){...  return 0; .... return 1;}` and test it in the main() or your validate().

```
int i=0;
int result=0;
while ( (result==0)&&(i<3) ){
  result=validate_pin();
  i++;
}
```

Dont use `goto`, **learn** to use loops.